# Vertically center image in column

Tags: html, css

I have two columns in my HTML page.

```
<div id="content">
  <div id="left"></div>
  <div id="right"></div>
</div>
```

Each of them occupies half of the page

```
#left {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}

#right {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}
```

I want to center a picture in the right column. I know that I can make it horizontally centered by doing `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;`. How can I make it vertically centered?

Comment: I think you just have to put a height 100% and then margin auto

Comment: Have you tired `vertical-align:middle` on the column div?

Comment: Not an answer but you should combine the `#left` and `#right` CSS blocks like so: `#left, #right { /* styles */ }`. You shouldn't repeat any code when programming and the same goes for CSS.

Comment: You could also add a common class between the two `div`s. Emphasis on class, not the same `id` twice.

Comment: Everybody here should be aware of the following: http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue I see is that there is no height specified for the height of the `left` and `right` `div`s; height should be set to `100%` or any value to your liking. To vertically center the image, we can use absolute-positioning. We would set the dimensions for the image (which is good practice in any case) and then set the `top:50%` and `left:50%` attributes. This would push the image outside the box though, so we add negative margins that are half the width and height of the image. This will vertically and horizontally align the image in a `div` **every time**!

Here's the updated CSS:

```
#left, #right {
width: 50%;
height:100%;
float:left;
position:relative;
}
#right img {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
width: 80%;
height: 80%;
margin-top: -40%; /* Half the height */
margin-left: -40%; /* Half the width */
}
```

Take a look at this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bYF7F/2/.

Comment: Thanks, I see what you're doing. But then the size of the image will always be 80% of the `right` div. Is it possible to get rid of that assumption, since some images are not appropriate to display at that size?

Comment: Yes. Sorry for the mistake, I fixed it so the image is in the right side. And also, you can definitely get rid of the assumption. You can use pixel values instead (although if you want a responsive design, percentage is the way to go).

Comment: Yes, certainly! I was just implementing it.

Comment: Glad it helped! (`vertical-align` can be such a pain sometimes...)

Answer (score 0):

I know this question has been marked as answered, but you did mention that the height and width on the image was not ideal. So i would like to suggest another solution.

Add:

```
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;
```

to the right div, and:

```
margin: auto;
```

to the image. I think this is what you were after. See fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Fqa7b/

Answer (score -2):

If you use a TABLE instead of a DIV it will center automatically.

Comment: That's unnecessarily cumbersome, don't you think?

Comment: Not at all. In fact much simpler. Also, with tables you have more control when you know how to use them.

Comment: Actually, this would be an example of an incorrect use of a `table`. Tables are to be used for only tabular data. So sure, you could use this, but it would be semantically incorrect. Also, tables aren't nearly as free-flowing as `div`s, part of the reason no modern sites use tables for layout purposes.

Comment: This approach is not accessible. and should be avoided if accessibility is important to you.

Comment: Not accessible? Only if the only coding that you understand is DIV.

Comment: When a screen reader tells the user that it is about to read a table and it does not contain tabular data, i would say that approach is not accessible.

Comment: If the table is marked up correctly, the screen reader will read the column and/or row heading as the user enters each new cell.